# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when adding a new record to DB

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to add new records to my MongoDB database. The records come in the form of an array, and then, for each record, I add it as a new item to MongoDB.
The problem is that every time I try to add some records (30-50 records) I get this message:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()`

followed by this one:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

This is the snippet I use for adding records:

```
// update the blacklist with a new entry
router.post("/updateBlacklist", async (req, res) => {
  req.body.product_id.forEach(async element => {
    const blacklistItem = new Blacklist({ product_id: element });
    try {
      const savedItem = await blacklistItem.save();
      res.json(savedItem);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json({ message: err });
    }
  });
});
```

The same warning appears also when I try to download some photos using this function:

```
router.post("/product_ids", async (req, res) => {
  await downloadPhotos(req.body.items_id);
});
```

the function I call inside this route:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const download = require("./utils/download");

const downloadPhotos = async itemsIDs => {
  try {
    console.log(itemsIDs.length);
    await itemsIDs.forEach(ID => {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://${process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY}:${
            process.env.SHOPIFY_PASSWORD
          }@blablabla.myshopify.com/admin/products/${ID}/images.json?fields=id, src`
        )
        .then((req, res) => {
          console.log(req.data.images[0].src);
          download(req.data.images[0].src, req.data.images[0].id, 3000);
        });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

and the `download` function:

```
const Fs = require("fs");
const Path = require("path");
const Axios = require("axios");

async function downloadImage(url, filename, timeout) {
  const appDir = Path.dirname(require.main.filename);
  const path = Path.resolve(appDir, "images", `${filename}.jpg`);

  const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path);

  const response = await Axios({
    url,
    method: "GET",
    responseType: "stream",
    timeout: timeout
  });

  response.data.pipe(writer);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on("finish", resolve);
    writer.on("error", reject);
  });
}

module.exports = downloadImage;
```

What am I doing wrong in this approach?

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

It's because of these lines:

```
res.json(savedItem);    
res.json({ message: err });
```

You're running these lines several times, because they are inside the loop, you can't respond a request more than once because the connection it's closed after the first call.

Try with this:

```
router.post("/updateBlacklist", async (req, res) => {
  const savedList = [];
  req.body.product_id.forEach(async element => {
    const blacklistItem = new Blacklist({ product_id: element });
    try {
      const savedItem = await blacklistItem.save();
      savedList.push(savedItem)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      savedList.push({ message: err });
    }
  });
  res.json(savedItem);
});
```

UPDATE (suggestion):

```
router.post("/updateBlacklist", async (req, res) => {
  const items = req.body.product_id.map(element => 
     new Blacklist({ product_id: element })
  });
  const result = await Blacklist.insertMany(items); // not sure about the syntax
  res.json(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved! Just now I get a 429, should I put a timer?

Comment: Instead of saving each item, try to save them all in a bulk.
`Blacklist.insertMany( items.. )`
It's only one call to the db which is faster.

Leave the loop only for creating the items list, just right before `res.json(..)` call the bulk method, you can find more info about this in MongoDB docs.

Comment: It seems the error does not go away, the array `req.body.product_id` is a list of ids, so I probably need to first transform it into an object, mapped `[product_id: 1, product_id:2...]`